# Can not read memory stream c#

Tags: c#, exception, stream, streamreader, memorystream

I am using some data, that goes to a mvc api. In this case, I pass the data using postman.
The data format is raw text. The value that I am passing to the API are the following,and represent EDF (http://www.edfplus.info/) data  :

```
  "rawdata":{

 "binaryencoding":"base64","FileID":3,"ExtensionName":"edf",

   "value":"gMnW5\/P5  \/Pz16+HZ087KyMbEwsHBwMDAwMHBwcLCw8PExMXFxsfHyMnJysvLy8zMy8vLysrKysnJycnJycrKysvLy8vMzMzMzc7Q0dLS0dHQzs3MysjHxcTCwL69u7m3trSysbCvra2sq6uqqqqqqqqqq6urrKysrK2tra.....QjY2SnKu7zNnb1Mi7sKehnJiWlJKRkZCQkJCRkZGSkpOTk5SUlJWVlpaXl5iYmZmampqam5qbm5ubm5ycnJ2dnp6fn6CgoaGioqGhoKCfnp6dnJybm5uampqamZmZmZiYmJeXlpaWlZWVlZSUlJOTk5KSkZGRkZGQkJCQkI+Pj4+Pj4+Pj..."
```

Here you are some code.To keep things simple, I will assign the rawdata.value from the httppost directly to an object that was created before, the Value is a string.

```
myObject.value=rawdata.value;
byte[] data=Base64.Convert.FromBase64String(myObject.value);(myobject.Value); //this gives you a 15.000 positions array.
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
//the stream gets those ReadTimeOut and WriteTimeOut exceptions,after being created
StreamReader Sr=new StreamReader(stream);
char[] header=new char[256];
sr.ReadBlock(header, 0, 256);
```

when you inspect the block, it has all its values like the following, with the � symbol:

`[0] = 65533 '�'`

I also have to add that I when I inspect the Stream, I can see that the stream readtimeout and writetimeout properties through the following error: `System.InvalidOperationException`

Do you know why this error might be occurring? thanks

Comment: This code makes no sense, can you tell us what the data is supposed to be/represent? We know you have *something* that is in base64 encoding, but what is that something?

Comment: I added more details, thanks

Comment: So the contents of that base64 encoded string is actually text? Is that it? Why are you using `.ReadBlock? How about just `.ReadLine`?

Comment: is there any difference?sorry for the question, I am newbie, could it be the error?I just need the first 256 positions of the streamreader, for this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be hat after the MemoryStream is created, the position is pointed at the end of the array. Have you tried this?

```
// this value comes from raw data, and for this example, lets suppose that it is all right.
byte[] data=Base64.bDecodingForString(Value);
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
//the stream gets those ReadTimeOut and WriteTimeOut exceptions,after being created
stream.Position = 0;
if(stream.CanRead) 
{
   StreamReader Sr=new StreamReader(stream);
   char[] header=new char[256];
   sr.ReadBlock(header, 0, 256);
}
else 
{
   //Show error
}
```

Comment: The initial position after the constructor has been called is position 0, even if you feed it a giant array as part of the constructor parameters. Your answer is a comment more than an answer.

Comment: It did not fix the problem, it continues giving me those strange values [0] = 65533 '�'   , thanks for your time